# Make Node Dynamic for Only One Object Swift and Spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am creating a space shooter game, and I want to make one of my nodes only be dynamic when it interacts with ones specific node, as opposed to all nodes. Essentially, I only want the node to act as dynamic when it interacts with one specified node. How can I do this?

Thanks.

I know the question is a but confusing, but if anyone has any ideas it would be extremely helpful!!

```
let Bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BulletGalaga.png")
            Bullet.zPosition = -5

            Bullet.position = CGPoint(x: ship.position.x, y: ship.position.y)
            Bullet.zRotation = ship.zRotation


            //let action = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(400 * cos(Bullet.zRotation),(400 * -sin(Bullet.zRotation))), duration: 0.8)

            let action = SKAction.move(
                to: CGPoint(
                    x: 1200 * -cos(Bullet.zRotation - 1.57079633) + Bullet.position.x,
                    y: 1200 * -sin(Bullet.zRotation - 1.57079633) + Bullet.position.y
                ),
                duration: 2.4)

            //let action = SKAction.moveToY(self.size.height + 30, duration: 0.8)
            //let action = SKAction.moveTo(self.ship.size.height, duration: 0.8)
            let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
            Bullet.run(SKAction.sequence([action, actionDone]), withKey: "bulletAction")

            Bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: Bullet.size)
            Bullet.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            Bullet.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
            self.addChild(Bullet)
```

I added this:

```
    ship.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = shipCategoryBitMask
    Bullet.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = bulletCategoryBitMask
    enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = enemyCategoryBitMask
    enemyBullet.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = enemyBulletCategoryBitMask

    ship.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = enemyBulletCategoryBitMask
    Bullet.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = enemyCategoryBitMask
    enemyBullet.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = shipCategoryBitMask
    enemy.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = bulletCategoryBitMask
```

Comment: @claassenApps It still isn't working

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not in a position to write any code out right now. I'll respond this evening - thanks.

Comment: @claassenApps great!! Thank you so much

Comment: @claassenApps are you willing to come up with some sort of example code now?

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay - I've been traveling most of the day. Your collisionBitMasks look as I'd expect. Can you post how you're setting up the ship, bullet, enemy, and enemyBullet categoryBitMasks (where you define what the bit masks are)? Also, your problem could also be that it looks like you're creating the bullet incorrectly. Do you have a class named Bullet? Where you create your bullet (let Bullet = ...), the color is blue where all your other variables aren't. Try making all the Bullets into lowercase bullets to create a different variable.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've set a SpriteNode's physics body, you can use the collisionBitMask to specify which other SpriteNodes it will collide with. You'll need to first set each node's physics body's categoryBitMask.

```
let node1CategoryBitMask = 0x1 << 0
let node2CategoryBitMask = 0x1 << 1
let node3CategoryBitMask = 0x1 << 2

node1.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = node1CategoryBitMask
node2.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = node2CategoryBitMask
node3.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = node3CategoryBitMask
```

At this point, three of the sprites have their categoryBitMask set. This is what identifies the physics body. Now to set the collisionBitMasks.

```
node1.collisionBitMask = node2CategoryBitMask
node2.collisionBitMask = node1CategoryBitMask | node3CategoryBitMask
```

This tells node1 to by collide with node2, but not node3. Node2 will collide with node1 and node3.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Should I make all of the dynamic then?

Comment: If you want the node's to be moved by other objects in the scene such as being pulled around by gravity or have one object move in reaction to being hit by another object, then  set dynamic = yes. If you want the node to be completely still all the time, then set dynamic = false.

Comment: Will making the nodes dynamic effect the solution you provided?

Comment: The method I provided basically lets you choose which nodes can collide with each other or pass straight through. It depends on whether you want the nodes to actually move around after you've collided with them or not. What behavior are you trying to accomplish when the two specific nodes collide?

Comment: So basically I have two ships, one that the player controls and an enemy ship controlled by the computer. They both shoot bullets. I wanted the dynamic affect on so that the bullet would push the other ship off the screen. The problem is that it also cause the ship that it's shooting from to glitch and change positions.

Comment: Can you post the code that runs when the glitch happens?

Comment: So the bullet that the player fires makes the player ship change position due to the physics bodies colliding? If so, changing the collisionBitMask of the bullet and player ship should fix it. Their physics bodies won't ever collide that way. Make sure you're setting both of them. The collisionBitMask for a nose defines all the physics bodies it is allowed to react to, so add all the categoryBitMasks you want the node to react to and leave out the ones you don't.

Comment: Can you post an example please? I'm not sure if that will work

Comment: Are you willing to write up some sort of example?